# Get picture from square AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, avfoundation

So what I am doing is creating a custom image picker, and I have a 320 X 320 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer that I am using, and when I take a picture, I want to get a UIImage of what is actually seen in the preview layer, but what I get when I take a photo with `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection: completionHandler:` is a normal image with size 2448 X 3264. So what would be the best way to get make this image into a 320 x 320 square image like is seen in the preview layer without messing it up? Is there a Right Way™ to do this? Also, I am using `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` for the `videoGravity` property of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, if that is relevant.

Comment: Hi, have you got an answer for your question ? We are exactly in the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to transform the image?

try using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(<#sx: CGFloat#>, <#sy: CGFloat#>)` to scale the image down. Transforms can do magic! If you have ever taken linear algebra, you should recall your standard transformation matrices. I have not used this for images, so I am not sure if this would work well with the pixels.

you could also try

```
// grab the original image
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    // scaling set to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size. 
    UIImage *scaledImage = 
                [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] 
                              scale:(originalImage.scale * 2.0)
                                 orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
```

where you can change the scale factor